# MySQL group by DAY in same table not working when count zero

Tags: mysql, sql

My following query not return row when COUNT(*) result return 0 row

```
SELECT COUNT(id) test,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_time)*1000 d 
FROM chat_table 
WHERE dept_id = 5 
   AND my_time >="2015-03-30" 
GROUP BY DAY(my_time) 
ORDER BY d ASC;
```

I need GROUP BY day even return 0 row. How can left join in same table? or any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have groups based on values that exist. If a value, for example, timestamp '2015-04-01 12:00:00' does not exist in your table, it cannot be part of the result.

You can work around this by:

- handling the results of the query in a programming language, supplementing count `0` for all rows that are missing
- OR creating a reference table that contains all timestamps
- OR manually injecting all timestamps using a subquery and union.

The best option is the first: keep your query as it is, but write logic in the program that starts the query to automatically assume that the count is zero if the timestamp is not in the result set.

For example, in PHP:

```
$countsPerTimestamp = array();
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $countsPerTimestamp[$row['d']] = $row['test'];
}

$searchTimestamp = '2015-04-05 12:13:14';
if (isset($countsPerTimestamp[$searchTimestamp])) {
    echo 'Count for now is: ' . $countsPerTimestamp[$searchTimestamp];
}
else {
    echo 'Count for now is: 0';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas, got an idea. I will group day in my programming as my day range is known

Comment: If the number of timestamps in the range is small, you can also join them like this: SELECT mtimestamp, count(id) from (select '2015-04-04 12:13:14' as mtimestamp UNION select '2015-04-04 12:13:15' UNION select '2015-04-04 12:13:16') as stamps left join chat_table on stamps.mtimestamp = chat_table.my_time group by mtimestamp

Answer (score 0):

If your table has data on every day but the `where` clause is filtering it out, then the easiest solution is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(dept_id = 5) as test,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_time)*1000 as d 
FROM chat_table 
WHERE my_time >= '2015-03-30'
GROUP BY DAY(my_time) 
ORDER BY d ASC;
```

If those conditions are not true, then you need to start with a list of all the dates and use `left join`.